# Solving equation with many exponents for same variable

Tags: binomial-theorem

$1.32=5(r + r^4) + 10 (r^2 + r^3) + r^5 + 1$

How would one solve an equation like this?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you tried taking the $\log$ of the function and using some logarithmic properties. Namely: $$\log(ab)=\log a + \log b$$ $$\log(a^n) = n\log a$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the RHS equals $(r+1)^5$, one has
$$1.32=(r+1)^5\Rightarrow r+1=1.32^{\frac 15}\Rightarrow r=1.32^{\frac 15}-1.$$

Comment: How did u arrive at the conculsion RHS equalls to (r+1)^5

Comment: ohh yea nvm binomial theorem

Comment: @dasith: Yes, the coefficients led me to the theorem.